# Stored procedure to convert multiple columns to one row

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, view

Is it possible to convert below current table into the target view using a stored procedure or view? `ID` is unique here and each `ID` may contain different type of accounts and each type can have more than 1 number. can anyone help ?

Current table (in SQL Server 2008):

```
ID  Type        Account   Balance
---------------------------------
1   checking    11111       100
1   checking    22222       200
1   savings     33333       300
1   savings     44444       400
2   investment  55555       500
2   checking    66666       600
```

Target (below record is for ID value 1)

```
Checking1_Account   Checking2_Account   Checking1_Balance   Checking2_Balance   Savings1_Account    Savings2_Account    Savings1_Balance    Savings2_Balance
11111   22222   100 200 33333   44444   300 400
```

Target (below record is for ID value 2)

```
Investment1_Account Investment1_Balance Checking1_Account   Checking1_Balance
55555   500 66666   600
```

Comment: A view has a fixed set of column definitions.  What are the columns you want for your view?

Comment: unfortunately my table structure is dynamic rows :( so columns need to be dynamic as well , Stored procedure can work as well if View is not an option

Comment: . . That rules out both a view and a table-valued function.  It also strongly suggests that you should reconsider your data model.

Comment: using the below table_view i'm able to display the results in this format
ID columnName columnValue
1 checkin1_Account 11111
1 checkin1_Balance 100
1 checkin2_Account 22222
1 checkin2_Balance 200
1 savings1_Account 33333
1 savings1_Balance 300
1 savings2_Account 44444
1 savings2_Balance 400
2 checkin1_Account 55555
2 checkin1_Balance 500
2 investment1_Account 66666
2 investment1_Balance 600

Comment: ;with cte as (
    Select *,RN   = Row_Number() over (Partition By ID,Type Order by Account)
     From  table
)
Select A.ID
      ,B.*
 From  cte A
 Cross Apply (values (concat(A.[Type],A.RN,'_Account'),A.Account)
                    ,(concat(A.[Type],A.RN,'_Balance'),A.Balance)
             ) B (columnName,columnValue)

Comment: and using the below SQL statement able to convert  table_view in to Target format 
Checking1_Account   Checking2_Account   Checking1_Balance   Checking2_Balance   Savings1_Account    Savings2_Account    Savings1_Balance    Savings2_Balance
11111   22222   100 200 33333   44444   300 400

Comment: DECLARE '@sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT '@sql =
'SELECT' + CHAR(10);

SELECT '@sql = '@sql + 
'   MAX(CASE WHEN ColumnName = ' +QUOTENAME(ColumnName, '''') + ' THEN ColumnValue END) AS ' + QUOTENAME(ColumnName) + ',' + CHAR(10)
FROM table_view;
SELECT '@sql = SUBSTRING('@sql, 0, LEN('@sql) - 1);

SELECT '@sql = '@sql + CHAR(10)
+ 'FROM table_view'
PRINT '@sql;
EXEC('@sql);
\end{CD}

Comment: but when i combine the view code with sql stament in to one sql statement , unable to get the same target result . error is 'common table expression defined but not used' , how can i fix this ?